# How to accurately position the labels in the container for different screen sizes?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I have some problems with positioning labels on top of the image for different screen sizes. Image size changes depending on the screen and labels must be **accurately** in some places over image. I read about adaptive interfaces and size classes, but linking to constrains is not accurately positioned labels and I do not know what to do. I will be very grateful for your help!

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0GGF.png)

Comment: do it programmatically

Comment: You need to be more specific. You can do many things with constraints in interface builder but without more information on what you want to do it is difficult to help.

Comment: @Ali Beadle I added image to my post. I try use constrains on every label and tying them to the edges, but when device with small sceen, all my label lose their place. And sorry for my question, i am new in iOS development :)

Comment: @Yume That looks relatively simple with interface builder and constraints - but unless you show us what you tried and what is going wrong we still can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two constraints to each label to fix it to the two edges of the image it needs to stay with. Then add constraints to the labels to fix their height and width. Check that the images also have constraints to fix their positions.

Answer (score 1):

Please use Auto Layout if you are not using.

Comment: Auto Layout is on in Interface Builder Document.

Answer (score 0):

Arrange the label relative to the Image on the screen.

Use Label.center or Label.frame attributes.

Hope it helps..